# How do I transpose selected number of rows and stack them on top of one another?

Tags: python, pandas, stack

I'm new to python and this is my first question on stackoverflow.

I have a pandas dataframe which contains the following rows (unknown number of rows):

```
 [[A],[B],[C],[A],[B],[C],...]
```

And I would like to convert the columns so the dataframe looks like this:

```
[[ABC],[ABC],[ABC],...]
```

There's probably a combination of groupbys but I've been scouring forums and books and I can't quite see it.

Comment: can you share the column names?

Comment: yeah, share an example dataframe with ur expected output

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. As it happens I managed to do it converting to np.array and reshape(-1,8) (8= number of columns).